Onn Tablet Pro 11 - Touch Screen Unresponsive to Stylus Input Until Touched
The moment you swap to a new app, program, window, or just wait about 5 to 10 seconds, the touch interface completely stops responding to a stylus. You then have to touch the screen with a finger and get it to move just a little before it starts accepting stylus input again; this problem repeats forever.
Four of the same tablets; all have the same problem.
Software updated on all four.
Screens are clean and problem happens with or without screen protectors.
Stylus works fine on any other touch screen product in the house.
Nothing changed in the consumer visible options related to sleep mode, touch, time-outs, or lock-outs fixed the issue.
Functionally it feels like the stylus touch just goes to sleep and needs to be woken up with a finger touch.
Any help or insight into this is appreciated.
